# Is it safe to charge a Li-Po battery at a lesser C rate than its usual routine?

Tags: battery-charging, charger, lipo

On my Quad Copter I have a 5400mAh Li-Po battery (3S 11.1V) and its charger charges at 0.5 C since it takes 2 hours to charge the battery.

That charger has broken down, I have ordered a replacement which will arrive in a few days, however I do have some other chargers that can charge at different rates.

There is one specific charger that only provides 1 Amp which is almost 1/3rd of the usual charge rate those batteries have been witnessing.

All I want to know is whether it is safe to charge a battery with less current than its regular cycle?

At 1 Amp it will take 5.4 hours to charge that battery. It is a balance charger like the existing one so balancing is not an issue. I'm fine with 5.4 hours I just don't want to ruin the battery.

Comment: Yes - provided the balance and charge termination is right.

Comment: This charger says its balance Accuracy is 10mV, is that fine enough? Don't exactly know the accuracy of the broken down one

Comment: Yes, 0.01V is good.

Comment: I realize you've learned this by now -- but a 5400mah battery will take much longer than 5.4 hours to charge at 1A.  The CV phase of the charge cycle is, by design, a lower amperage rating than the CC (1 amp) phase.  This will likely take 7+ hours to charge.

Comment: @insta im afraid thats not the case. A good lipo battery wont be at 0 mah charge level ever to start with. Its almost always 50%+ and better users will not even go below 60% charge level. So a 5400mah battery at 1c will take even less than 5.4 hours to charge

Comment: Nah you're just not flying it hard enough ;)  Good lipo chemistry will handle just under 3.0v/cell, and 18650s in their steel canisters are spec'ed (by the datasheets!) with a discharge voltage of 2.5v/cell.  When you pull them down this far, they do indeed take their labelled milliamps to recharge, and it does indeed take more than 1 hour to do it.  You probably should have mentioned you were charging from a storage charge level in the question, that could change answers.

Comment: Thats awesome def need one!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can always charge a Li-ion or Li-Po battery at *less* than its specified rate provided that *all* the normal charging requirements (CC followed by CV, don't overcharge, don't trickle-charge, don't let the battery get too warm or too cold, etc.) are adhered to.

Comment: Thanks! is 10mV Accuracy for a 3-S balance charger reasonable?

Comment: Do you have the datasheet for the battery?

Comment: It's this battery exactly: http://www.markertek.com/productImage/HI-RES/YUN-Q500BATTERY.JPG . It's discharge rate is not mentioned even online unfortunately

Comment: But they do mention *Never charge above 1C*  so i guess anything below 5.5 Amps should be fine